# Internal path versus http paths

Tags: html, path

Say for instance that you have the following path on a website:

```
/site/resources/img/bigImage.jpg
```

Now say that you replaced that path with the following path:

```
http://www.mydomain/site/resources/img/bigImage.jpg
```

is there a difference ( and i mean in performance) and if so how many images does it have to be for the site to be slowed down?

Comment: mostly I prefer to use relative url..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are relative and absolute URLs. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005079/absolute-vs-relative-urls) for thorough coverage of the topic, but best practices recommend relative URLs - i.e. `/site/resources/img/bigImage.jpg`

**Edit**: here's an [article](http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/design/relative_and_absolute_urls.php3) on the relative vs. URL question, which makes a good point: you will see a slight file size reduction with relative URLs. Unless you're looking at a huge number of images it probably won't be a major difference, but smaller is better when it comes to file size.

Comment: File size is a good point!

Answer (score 0):

Use relative URLs in all instances where they are suitable to make your site work on any machine. If you use external URLs, your site will only be defined at one domain.

---

There is really no difference you will notice in performance, but as a general rule, it is better to use relative URLs in practice.